# How to find the RAM type in command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, memory

How to find the RAM type (DDR2/DDR3) of the system using command prompt?

I have tried `SYSTEMINFO` in command prompt but it did not display the RAM type.

Comment: Do you know the model of your motherboard? If not, see this http://superuser.com/questions/175213/find-out-what-the-motherboard-on-my-computer-is then look up the manual to find out!

Comment: There is very likely a good duplicate on SU, but the one marked is definitely NOT a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed. A couple of the “answers” to that other question are actually answers to this question; i.e., they were posted in the wrong place. In particular, [@terdon’s `lshw` answer](https://superuser.com/q/573375/150988#573381) to the other question might make a valuable addition to this thread (except for the fact that it’s Linux-centric, and this question is about Windows). But the linked question is not a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 101):

You can use the [`wmic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) command to find out the information about your memory:

```
wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel, Capacity, MemoryType, TypeDetail, Speed
```

The MemoryType returns the type of your Memory: 21=DDR-2 etc. [Here is a complete list of information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory) you can get from the MemoryChip Class.

In my case unfortunately the type is unknown (0), but I still get some useful information:

[image: wmic output]

Comment: Thank u. When I enter this command it displays memory type as 21 which is equal to DDR2, but the actual memory type in my slot is DDR3. It does confusing.pls explain.

Comment: @baaljiav: What do CPU-Z, Speccy etc. show? Is there any specific reason you want to display the info at the command prompt?

Comment: @Karan, Wouldn't CPU-Z show the same as the cmd? Indeed wouldn't the cmd be more reliable than CPU-Z?

Comment: @Pacerier: Phew, you're asking me about a comment posted almost 2 years back! From what I see I was responding to the OP saying that wmic's output wasn't matching the actual memory he installed, and thus suggested double-checking with CPU-Z, Speecy and the like.

Comment: @Karan, How does CPU-Z do it then, if cmd is not able to do it?

Comment: @Pacerier: Why, are you claiming CPU-Z and wmic (not cmd) employ the exact same code? If you want to know how CPU-Z works you can get hold of its source code if available and check. Also, I'm not the one claiming that wmic cannot do something. The OP said wmic's output doesn't match reality, so perhaps you should ask him whether he found CPU-Z's output more in line with his expectations or not. Good luck with that though given how old this question is. I am not going to debate any more about simple suggestions I made in a comment 2 years ago.

Comment: If you see a 0 there, there are chances that it’s a DDR4 RAM, unknown to WMIC command.

Comment: [An answer by “myrobostation BG”](https://superuser.com/q/606318/150988#1289937) suggests adding the `DeviceLocator` property.

Comment: @Pacerier cmd doesn't do anything. It's [`wmic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) that does the job. But the implementation in wmic is old and hasn't been updated to the latest SMBIOS specs so it doesn't recognize anything beyond DDR2. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1540441/241386) for an updated solution. CPU-Z and Speccy are doing the same way to detect memory configuration

Comment: Does not work with DDR4

Answer (score 38):

There is software out there that gathers information on some of the main devices of your system.

These program will display the details for you (and more). One example is [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).  A screenshot that shows the information you are looking for:

[image: Screenshot]

Now, as per the excellent comment left by [Breakthrough](https://superuser.com/users/6887/breakthrough) (I've copied it in case for any reason he decides to delete his comment):

> You can run CPU-Z from a command prompt, and using the -txt=report.txt will place the CPU-Z output into the file report.txt without invoking the GUI (it also mentions a -console switch to output the information to STDOUT, but says it works under Windows XP only for some reason). See [additional parameters here](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html#directiontouse) for additional details. – [Breakthrough](https://superuser.com/users/6887/breakthrough)

Comment: Note that CPU-Z must be run as administrator (i.e., with elevated permissions)  to be able to get information on memory.

Comment: Useless, only says "4 Gbytes" and nothing else

Answer (score 16):

For a better look of the output, consider adding `list full` after `wmic memorychip`.

i.e., open cmd then type `wmic memorychip list full`

[image]

Comment: Look at the `MemoryType=0` line, wmic can't detect DD4 or other new types of memory because it hasn't been updated to the latest SMBIOS spec so don't use it. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1540441/241386) for a solution that actually works

Answer (score 10):

`wmic MemoryChip` is highly outdated and **doesn't show correct outputs for DDR3 and up**. I've written a PowerShell script that reads the raw SMBIOS tables and parse the *Memory Device* table (Type 17). Currently it's based on [SMBIOS specification version 3.4.0a](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.4.0a.pdf) and will need to be updated in the future if there any new RAM types in the new spec

Sample output:

```
D:\> .\ram_type.ps1
Size: 8,589,934,592 bytes (8 GB)
Memory form factor: 0x09 DIMM
Memory type: 0x1A (DDR4)
Type detail: 0x80 (Synchronous)
Speed: 2,666 MT/s
=======================
Size: 8,589,934,592 bytes (8 GB)
Memory form factor: 0x09 DIMM
Memory type: 0x1A (DDR4)
Type detail: 0x80 (Synchronous)
Speed: 2,666 MT/s
=======================
```

Here's the script. Tested on many PCs with DDR3 and DDR4. On many cases you'll see "0 GB" entries because there are still empty slots in the machine

Just save it as *.ps1 and run, or copy the whole script and paste into PowerShell

```bsh
# Based on System Management BIOS (SMBIOS) Reference Specification 3.4.0a
# https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.4.0a.pdf

# 7.18.1. Form factor @offset 0x0E
[string[]]$FORM_FACTORS = @(
    'Invalid', 'Other', 'Unknown', 'SIMM',                      # 00-03h
    'SIP', 'Chip', 'DIP', 'ZIP'                                 # 04-07h
    'Proprietary Card', 'DIMM', 'TSOP', 'Row of chips',         # 08-0Bh
    'RIMM', 'SODIMM', 'SRIMM', 'FB-DIMM',                       # 0C-0Fh
    'Die'                                                       # 10h
)
# 7.18.2. Memory type @offset 0x12
[string[]]$MEMORY_TYPES = @(
    'Invalid',  'Other',    'Unknown',  'DRAM',                 # 00-03h
    'EDRAM',    'VRAM',     'SRAM',     'RAM',                  # 04-07h
    'ROM',      'FLASH',    'EEPROM',   'FEPROM',               # 08-0Bh
    'EPROM',    'CDRAM',    '3DRAM',    'SDRAM',                # 0C-0Fh
    'SGRAM',    'RDRAM',    'DDR',      'DDR2',                 # 10-13h
    'DDR2 FB-DIMM', 'Reserved', 'Reserved', 'Reserved',         # 14-17h
    'DDR3',     'FBD2',     'DDR4',     'LPDDR',                # 18-1Bh
    'LPDDR2',   'LPDDR3',   'LPDDR4',   'Logical non-volatile device' # 1C-1Fh
    'HBM (High Bandwidth Memory)', 'HBM2 (High Bandwidth Memory Generation 2)',
        'DDR5', 'LPDDR5'                                        # 20-23h
)
# 7.18.3. Type detail @offset 0x13
[string[]]$TYPE_DETAILS = @(
    'Reserved', 'Other', 'Unknown', 'Fast-paged',               # bit 0-3
    'Static column', 'Pseudo-static', 'RAMBUS', 'Synchronous',  # bit 4-7
    'CMOS', 'EDO', 'Window DRAM', 'Cache DRAM',                 # bit 8-11
    'Non-volatile', 'Registered (Buffered)',
        'Unbuffered (Unregistered)', 'LRDIMM'                   # 0C-0Fh
)

function lookUp([string[]]$table, [int]$value)
{
    if ($value -ge 0 -and $value -lt $table.Length) {
        $table[$value]
    } else {
        "Unknown value 0x{0:X}" -f $value
    }
}

function parseTable([array]$table, [int]$begin, [int]$end)
{
    [int]$index = $begin
    $size = [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($table, $index + 0x0C)
    if ($size -eq 0xFFFF) {
        "Unknown memory size"
    } elseif ($size -ne 0x7FFF) {
        if (($size -shr 15) -eq 0) { $size *= 1MB } else { $size *= 1KB }
        # if ([Math]::Floor($size/32768) -eq 0) { $size *= 1MB } else { $size *= 1KB } # For PowerShell < 3.0
    } else {
        $size = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($table, $index + 0x1C)
    }
    "Size: {0:N0} bytes ({1} GB)" -f $size, ($size/1GB)

    $formFactor = $table[$index + 0x0E]
    $formFactorStr = $(lookUp $FORM_FACTORS $formFactor)
    "Memory form factor: 0x{0:X2} {1}" -f $formFactor, $formFactorStr

    $type = $table[$index + 0x12]
    "Memory type: 0x{0:X2} ({1})" -f $type, $(lookUp $MEMORY_TYPES $type)

    $typeDetail = [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($table, $index + 0x13)
    $details = 0..15 |% {
        if (((1 -shl $_) -band $typeDetail) -ne 0) { "{0}" -f $TYPE_DETAILS[$_] }
        # if (([int]([Math]::Pow(2, $_)) -band $typeDetail) -ne 0) { "{0}" -f $TYPE_DETAILS[$_] } # For PowerShell < 3.0
    }
    "Type detail: 0x{0:X2} ({1})" -f $typeDetail, $($details -join ' | ')

    $speed = [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($table, $index + 0x15)
    if ($speed -eq 0) {
        "Unknown speed"
    } elseif ($speed -ne 0xFFFF) {
        "Speed: {0:N0} MT/s" -f $speed
    } else {
        "Speed: {0:N0} MT/s" -f [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($table, $index + 0x54)
    }
    "======================="
}

$index = 0

$END_OF_TABLES = 127
$MEMORY_DEVICE = 17

$BiosTables = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName . -Namespace root\wmi -Query `
    "SELECT SMBiosData FROM MSSmBios_RawSMBiosTables" `
).SMBiosData

do
{
    $startIndex = $index

    # ========= Parse table header =========
    $tableType = $BiosTables[$index]
    if ($tableType -eq $END_OF_TABLES) { break }

    $tableLength = $BiosTables[$index + 1]
    # $tableHandle = [BitConverter]::ToUInt16($BiosTables, $index + 2)
    $index += $tableLength

    # ========= Parse unformatted part =========
    # Find the '\0\0' structure termination
    while ([BitConverter]::ToUInt16($BiosTables, $index) -ne 0) { $index++ }
    $index += 2

    # adjustment when the table ends with a string
    if ($BiosTables[$index] -eq 0) { $index++ }

    if ($tableType -eq $MEMORY_DEVICE) { parseTable $BiosTables $startIndex $index }
} until ($tableType -eq $END_OF_TABLES -or $index -ge $BiosTables.length)
```

Comment: This is the only reliable answer that doesnt require third party software and is backed by the specification. Why is this the second lowest answer?

Comment: Does work as advertised. Needs additional info on how to execute. I stored in `c:\tmp\getMemoryInfo.ps1` In Powershell I did the following:
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process` and then
`c:\tmp\getMemoryInfo.ps1`

The first command was required to allow the execution of an unsigned script.

Comment: @OliverMeyer you don't need to set the execution policy if you copy and paste directly into PowerShell

Comment: When I try to run this script in PowerShell, I get “You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.” on line 50, char 21 (the first dash in `if (($size -shr 15) -eq 0)`). This is on a very old machine running Windows 7, so probably an ancient version of PowerShell too – could that be why?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, shift operators have only been added [since PowerShell 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7.1) while Windows 7 was shipped with PS 2.0. So just replace that right shift by `[math]::floor($size/32767)`. Do the same for the remaining shifts. Can you check the updated code to see if it's working?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes that's a shift-left. You don't need to use floor in this case. And the number should be 32768 for both cases, my bad. I've updated the code in the answer, just copy them out and toggle the comment on the 2 lines with shift

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet fixed the bracket and tested on my PC

Comment: Yes, works like a charm now!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative you can use, which is free, is [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy)... by the same people who make CCleaner.

It gives you all your hardware specs, as well as temps, voltages, and other data in real time

Comment: Note that Speccy must be run as administrator (i.e., with elevated permissions) to be able to get information on memory.

Comment: this doesn't actually answer the question which is about getting the RAM type in *command prompt*

Answer (score 2):

While many answers note that `wmic` is obsolete, you can get the part number right and google that:

```
wmic memorychip get partnumber
```

Usually a Google search using just the part number will return several pages where the memory specs are detailed.

Perhaps really old RAM parts will not return useful results, but then `wmic` should work on these really old RAM sticks.

Answer (score -1):

Open the Command Prompt from the Start menu. You can also press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type cmd to start it.

Type `wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Speed` and press <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>

The `BankLabel` column will tell you which slots the RAM chips are installed in.

Comment: how is this different from the current top voted answer? And the OP is asking about memory type (DDR2, DDR3, etc.) not about the bank, but wmic command doesn't work for DDR3, DDR4 and up

Answer (score -2):

1. Go To `Start` (Or `Ask me anything`) and type in `Cmd` then click on `CommandPrompt`
2. In console window type (or paste) `wmic MemoryChip`

You should get the full information about your RAM

[image: wmic MemoryChip output]

Answer (score -2):

For me, I can't see the voltage of the RAMs on my laptops for some reason using any of the programs mentioned above...

If you have the same problem as me, once you find the part number using cmd (see the picture above by other posts)

```
wmic memorychip list full
```

Google the part number, and you shall be able to find more relevant information on your RAM.

Firstly by part no. (eg. HMT451S6AFR8C-PB)
the webpage is no longer available but there's cache on google! XD
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8vi-pY_TttYJ:https://schreibfehler.eu/w-123/hmt451s6afr8c-pb.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sg&client=firefox-b

From the webpage I found out the name and maker of the RAM, then I searched again with voltage as search string: "SK HYNIX 4GB 1Rx8 PC3 12800S voltage"

https://www.ebay.com/p/SK-Hynix-4gb-Pc3-12800-Ddr3-204-pin-SODIMM-1-35v-Low-Voltage/664910591

I guess you can try searching directly in ebay as there is a lot of second hand parts on sale on ebay and your ram might just pop up on the list using part no. as the search string.