# Is there any way to find out the motherboard for my dell e6420 without opening the machine?

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard

Is there any way to find out the motherboard for my dell e6420 without opening the machine?

I want to find out the maximum and type of ram.

Comment: On laptops it's generally going to be a proprietary motherboard specific to that model.  But you can find out what type of RAM separately from knowing the motherboard.  Run a utility like CPU-Z or google "Dell E6420 Service Manual" to find a PDF which lists the specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Command Prompt enter:

```
wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber
```

That should give you what you're looking for your motherboard.

You can type:

```
wmic baseboard get /?
```

for more options.

The second question looks like it has [an answer already](https://superuser.com/questions/606318/how-to-find-the-ram-type-in-command-prompt).

[This tool](http://www.filehippo.com/download_speccy/download/60ffc532a5e5ef0d1a1e1182a40f592f/) (called speccy) works well and gives the info you are looking for.

Some sources:

http://www.howtogeek.com/208420/how-to-check-your-motherboard-model-number-on-your-windows-pc/

http://www.nextofwindows.com/4-ways-to-find-out-whats-the-motherboard-model-inside-your-windows-7-machine/

[How to find the Ram type in command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/606318/how-to-find-the-ram-type-in-command-prompt)

Comment: Thanks. Once I am certain of the motherboard, I can find the ram.

Comment: Great, that link to the tool (called speccy) works great, I found it and tried it before posting to make sure, it gives a lot of info.

Comment: Speccy is very good. Add it to your answer and I will accept. Max recommended for my motherboard is 8GB