# How to tell if a RAM module (DDR3) is buffered or unbuffered RAM?

Tags: memory

[image]

I have an HP Desktop 705 G1 SFF(small form factor) that supports DIMM - DDR3, non-ECC, unbuffered RAM, with max support for 1600 MHz.

I bought a pair of DDR3 RAM sticks (the one in pic) which has the capacity of 8GB - 1600 Mhz, to replace the ones that was used in the motherboard. The old RAM is also 8 GB, but has a lower clock speed of 1333 Mhz.

Once the RAM was installed on the motherboard, I checked Task Manager/ Memory, and it showed the speed of 1600 Mhz. By looking at the chip counts, I know that these are non-ECC modules (these sticks have 8 memory chips on each side).

But, how to verify that these are unbuffered modules? (since, some items listed on Amazon.com don't function exactly as described).

Comment: Based on your description the module works. Therefore you can simply use [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to get more details on the used module.

Comment: The simplest way would be to look at the specification page for the module not the manufactures website.  Amazon does not actually review product descriptions.  You can flag if a product description is inaccurate.  Is there a reason you replaced your DDR3 modules with whats virtually identical memory?  You will see no performance increase going from 1333 MHz to 1600 Mhz.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the RAM type in command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/606318/how-to-find-the-ram-type-in-command-prompt)

Comment: I refer specially to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1540441/8672).

Comment: @Ramhound I thought the PC would run somewhat faster, and smoother thanks to the faster processing speed of the RAM. I set the page file size at 8 GB, or 10 GB; and the 8 GB physical RAM is handling the current work loads pretty well. If necessary, I would add some more RAM.

Comment: You won't be able to detect any performance gains by upgrading to 1600 MHz.  If you were talking about 1333 MHz to 4000 MHz you might see that, but outside of benchmarks, you might not even notice that.  What does your page file have to do with the frequency of the memory?  Adding more memory won't provide a performance increase unless you are running out of memory.

Comment: @Robert I've just tried CPU-Z, but the CPU-Z Memory tab doesn't display any specific info refers to if the Ram modules are buffered or unbuffered.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks! I will look into that. I've tried the cmd wmic memorychip command( one of the solutions mentioned), but for some reason, for some properties' values, my cmd returns no values. Probably, those values are not available for DDR3 modules using the command. I'll try different methods mentioned in the answer section.

Comment: @domino But you now have the details product number and can use it to search the Internet for the complete specification. And as your set-up works there is no pressure. Who cares if the module is buffered (IMHO unlikely) or not.